# How do I parallelise this DFS?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, tree, binary, depth-first-search

I have a binary tree where each node has the value of 0 or 1, and each path from the `root` to leaf node represents a binary string of a certain length. The aim of the program is to find all possible binary `String` (i.e. all possible paths from `root` to leaf). Now I want to parallelise it, so that it can use multiple cores. I assume I need to somehow split up the workload on the branch nodes, but I have no idea where to begin. I am looking at the `ForkJoin` functionality, but I have no idea how to split up the work and then combine it.

```
public class Tree{
  Node root;
  int levels;

  Tree(int v){
    root = new Node(v);
    levels = 1;
  }
  Tree(){
    root = null;
    levels = 0;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Tree tree = new Tree(0);
    populate(tree, tree.root, tree.levels);
    tree.printPaths(tree.root);
  }

  public static void populate(Tree t, Node n, int levels){
    levels++;
    if(levels >6){
      n.left = null;
      n.right = null;
    }
    else{
      t.levels = levels;
      n.left = new Node(0);
      n.right = new Node(1);
      populate(t, n.left, levels);
      populate(t, n.right, levels);
    }
  }
  
  void printPaths(Node node)
   {
       int path[] = new int[1000];
       printPathsRecur(node, path, 0);
   }

  void printPathsRecur(Node node, int path[], int pathLen)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;

        /* append this node to the path array */
        path[pathLen] = node.value;
        pathLen++;

        /* it's a leaf, so print the path that led to here  */
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null)
            printArray(path, pathLen);
        else
        {
            /* otherwise try both subtrees */
            printPathsRecur(node.left, path, pathLen);
            printPathsRecur(node.right, path, pathLen);
        }
    }

    /* Utility function that prints out an array on a line. */
    void printArray(int ints[], int len)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(ints[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Thread Pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) to efficiently split the load between separate threads.

One possible approach:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

Runnable recursiveRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your recursive code goes here (for every new branch you have a runnable (recommended to have a custom class implementing Runnable))
    }
};
service.execute(recursiveRunnable);
```

However, this approach is no longer a deep first search, since you list the sub-branches for your position before searching through the first one. In my understanding, DFS is a strictly linear approach and is therefore not entirely parallelizable (feel free to correct me in the comments though).

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. I know, I haven't been able to find much info about parallelised DFS other than "it's difficult". The code I provided is an extremely simplified version of something I will be doing, and it will require a DFS.

Comment: Note: I just winged that code so there might be some syntax errors.
Note 2: If you need DFS due to its specific execution order then you can't make it parallel because you cannot assure that the order will remain in any form. For general purposes it should be good enough.